# Wildfly "Lazy-Inits" Filters, can I change that?

Tags: java, spring, jboss, servlet-filters, wildfly

I think I 've found a difference in the implementation of Filter initialization between Jetty and Wildfly.

I 've a web application using Tapestry, Spring and Hibernate. I 'm trying to migrate it from Jetty to Wildfly.

My web.xml has two filters:

Firstly the OpenSessionInViewFilter (which requires the WebApplicationContext to exist when doInternalFilter is executed). This filter needs to be before Tapestry's so that the hibernate session embraces all Tapestry activity against the backend database.

Second to that is the Tapestry framework (w/ spring integration) Filter which in it's *init* method loads the spring's WebApplicationContext.

I was running this scenario without a problem in Jetty (also in Tomcat), but when moving it to Wildfly the OpenSessionInViewFilter threw an IllegalStateException telling that no WebApplicationContext was found.

I tried debugging this and found out that Wildfly is not calling the *init* Filter method until that Filter receives the first request to process. I agree this could be a performance improvement in certain scenarios but it's a problem in my current scenario.

Is there any way to tell Wildfly to init filters on the application startup?

thank you.

Comment: That looks like a nice enhancement we could add to wildfly/undertow, could you create jira for this? https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY

Comment: Ok, so you 're saying it's not possible to do this (unless you change the source code of course) :D So I 'll add a JIRA as you suggest. If you want you could add an answer saying "it's not possible, just fill a JIRA" so I would mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Comment: I 've already filled a JIRA, here's the link: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-3028

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I sent [pull request](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/6007) that exposes this functionality via configuration option in undertow subsystem.

you can now add

```
<servlet-container name="default" eager-filter-initialization="true">
```

to enable this.

Comment: Thank You!! Not only you provided the answer but also the solution.

Thank you so much again